# Write only property in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, properties, accessor

I am stuck with objective-c properties. What I need is to assign a write-only property for a variable, exactly the opposite of readonly, i.e the variable can have `setMethod`, but it should not have `getMethod`. I don't know how to do it. answers with some code snippets are appreciated.

Comment: What's the use of write-only property? IMHO it's only a waste of memory.

Comment: Lots of uses; typically when you want something to be publicly write-only and internally-to-the-class it is readwrite.

Comment: When an outside class knows a variable that needs to be passed in but has no reason to know what it's currently set to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
@interface MyClass {
@private
int _var;
}

- (void)setVar:(int)newVar;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (void)setVar:(int)newVar {
_var = newVar;
}
@end
```

Now you can access the variable `var` like a property that is write-only:

```
@implementation SomeOtherClass
...
MyClass c = [[MyClass alloc] init];
c.var = 3;
...
@end
```

And if you try to read the fake property the compiler will warning you.

Comment: Need to define a method `-(void)setVar:(int)newVar` in the implementation as well as the interface.

Comment: Be aware that this does not completely hide the value. Unless you override (BOOL)accessInstanceVariablesDirectly with NO, you can get the value with valueForKey:@"var". And even if you override this, you can still get the value with a objC-runtime method like object_getInstanceVariable.

Comment: @kubbing Technically it is a property. A property in Obj-C is just a fancy name for two methods, getter & setter. You can declare a getter without using `@property` and the behavior will be exactly the same as with `@property`. The same applies for setter. You can even use the dot notation.

Comment: @Sulthan That is almost correct, a part from the fact that the runtime makes this distinction. A *fake* property like this one, won't be for instance listed when using `class_copyPropertyList`. See my answer for a different approach.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella That's true but in 99% of cases the difference doesn't matter. Giving you a +1 anyway cause it's a nice solution :)

Comment: @Sulthan Agreed. Probably the greatest advantage of my solution is autocompletion (and it's shorter too ;) ).

Comment: Having it be a real property makes a difference if you use the class with Swift. If it is not a property you can't use dot-notation in Swift.

Answer (score 54):

Another valid approach is to declare the normal property and make the getter unavailable

```
@interface MyClass
@property NSString * var;
- (NSString *)var UNAVAILABLE_ATTRIBUTE;
@end
```

This will raise a compile-time error in case someone tries to access the getter.

---

The main advantage of this approach is that you actually have a **real property<sup>TM</sup>** and not a surrogate faked by a instance variable and a setter, which implies that:

- you'll get auto-completion when using dot-notation in Xcode
- all the runtime functions such as `class_getProperty` and 
  `class_copyPropertyList` will work as expected.

That said, the getter implementation is synthesized anyway and it could be invoked using something like

```
NSString * string = [myObj performSelector:@selector(var)];
```

or using `NSInvocation` (in case of a non-`id` property)

If you are paranoid and you *really* want to prevent the client to invoke the getter, you can explicitly throw an exception by providing your own implementation.

```
@implementation MyClass
- (int)var {
    [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                format:@"property is write-only"];
}
@end
```

Anyway, if someone seriously wants to tamper with your instance variable, they can use the runtime to access it, so the last precaution is probably useless given the use case. A compile-time error is what you are really looking for.

Comment: is it available to LLVM?

Answer (score 5):

Is there any reason this needs to be a property? I'd just declare the setter as a method and use the normal `[foo setVar:bar]` syntax.

Comment: Yes, that works, but xCode does not seem to auto-complete var when you type.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson you're right. For an auto-complete friendly solution, you may want to check out my solution.