# iOS property with only setter method

Tags: ios, properties

My understanding of properties is that they just construct getter and setter methods. Is there a way to create a property that just has a setter method? My question is similar to this [Write only property in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266197/write-only-property-in-objective-c) but it looks like the only solutions given are explicitly declaring and defining a setter method. Is that the only way or can it be done with properties?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you can have IOS automatically synthesize a "write only" property, than no. However, you can explicitly set a getter method that returns nil.

Example:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString;

-(NSString *)myString
{
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Even better, use `@dynamic` to prevent a synthesized getter. Then, trying to read the property will throw an exception since the getter does not exist. Of course, this requires you to provide your own setter, but a synthesized setter probably isn't useful in the case where you don't want a getter.